# IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range. Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to save prefabs in a two-dimensional array and Instantiate a prefab in a grid but in the `for` loop i get an error.

this is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wx83b.jpg)

but you get to see in the hierarchy when they are created
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ptnbh.jpg)

Comment: Please include your code as actual text inside your question body - don't post images of the code, as this makes it harder for people to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your screenshot, you are accessing your tablero array using `tablero[i,j]`.  You condition for your inner loop is `i<numColumnas` when it should be `j<numColumnas` otherwise your j will go past your number of column's and access an out of bounds index.

In your other screenshot, if you take a look at your log you should have been able to identify that your j was 2, which is the same size of your numColumnas which should have given it away(since your conditional is < and not <=).  Your logs are there for a reason.